# Allow others to develop plugins for my app

Tags: java, android, plugins

I'm developing [a home screen replacement for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.robinj.ubuntu) with search functionality in the app drawer. I not only want to allow (not force) users to search for installed apps, but also other content like Stack Overflow, Wikipedia or their local files.

Currently I'm developing these so-called "Lenses" myself, but I thought it'd be a cool idea if others could develop them as well. So what I'm wondering is if there's any way to allow other developers to do just that; Developing additional lenses for my app.

All lenses should inherit from the following class;

## `Lens.java`

```
public abstract class Lens
{
    protected Context context;

    protected Lens (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public abstract List<LensSearchResult> search (String str) throws IOException, JSONException;

    public abstract String getName ();

    public abstract String getDescription ();

    public void onClick (String url)
    {
        if (url.startsWith ("http://") || url.startsWith ("https://"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData (Uri.parse (url));

            this.context.startActivity (intent);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException ();
        }
    }

    public void onLongPress (String url)
    {
    }

    protected String downloadStr (String url) throws IOException, JSONException
    {
        // Not important. Provided for convenience.
    }

    protected Drawable downloadImage (String url) throws IOException, JSONException
    {
        // Not important. Provided for convenience.
    }
}
```

The developer should pass `Context` from their constructor to the superclass, implement `List<LensSearchResult> search (String str)`, `String getName ()`, and `String getDescription ()`. If we're talking about a URL, that's all they need to do. Otherwise they should also override `void onClick (String url)` and if they wish to do so `void onLongPress (String url)`.
That's basically what a "Lens" would consist of.

So what would I have to do (if at all possible) to make it possible for other developers to create "Lenses" for my app? Ideally they would be able to distribute them in, for example, the Google Play Store, but if necessary I can develop my own platform where others could upload their lenses. Either way I'd still need some way to run someone else's code from within my app.

Comment: "Either way I'd still need some way to run someone else's code from within my app" -- not if you have any sense. Otherwise, you will be a vehicle for malware.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do plan on implementing some kind of "trust list" to work around this, but in the end, is this any different from a user installing an app from the Play Store?

Comment: "is this any different from a user installing an app from the Play Store?" -- yes, in that apps run in separate processes. Your current API is not designed around IPC and appears to be designed to try having third-party code run in your own process, which is a security hole.

Comment: @CommonsWare Dashclock does something like that though. Users just install another 'extension' app. The app itself is open source, so that might be a good place to start.

Comment: @NiekHaarman: "Dashclock does something like that though" -- with an API designed for IPC, no requirements of magic classes to extend, etc. If somebody wants to provide a convenience JAR for third-party developers to use, that's fine, but the underlying protocol needs to be something designed for and implemented by IPC.

Comment: @CommonsWare In a sepaate thread, but I guess that doesn't make much difference. Don't browser extensions also run in the same process? If you can think of a better way (perhaps like what DashClock does) I'm all ears :) I've never done this before, which is why I posted this question. If I'm all on the wrong track here, please do correct me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you can think of a better way (perhaps like what DashClock does) I'm all ears :)

Design your API around IPC. Have third-party plugins implement a `Service`, a `ContentProvider`, and/or a `BroadcastReceiver` that your host app works with. While a bound service using AIDL would seem to be the most natural way of converting your existing API to one that uses IPC, bound services for plugins have all sorts of issues (e.g., API versioning) that are messy to deal with over time.

In your own app, you might wrap the low-level IPC plumbing in some classes that resemble your existing API. And if you wanted to have third-party developers use some library that you publish to have them create their plugins, you're welcome to do that too. You'll want to create a few plugins yourself, to test out your API and provide samples for third-party developers.

Given all of that, there are any number of ways that you can discover when plugins are installed and removed. `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` broadcasts, for example, can tell you when other apps are added and removed. You can then use `PackageManager` to see if they are one of your plugins (e.g., do they implement your IPC endpoint?). Or, use methods on `PackageManager` like `queryIntentServices()` to poll for plugin implementations, if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks! This at least gives me some idea of where to look :)

Comment: @RobinJ: Writing a plugin architecture is complex -- one could write a short book on the subject. There can be lots of dirty details, such as plugin lifecycle, security (e.g., preventing other apps from spoofing calls to the plugin), dealing with old plugins/new hosts (or new plugins/old hosts), and so on. I'm not saying "don't write it", but make sure that you have a clear reason why you are writing it, one that you feel fairly confident will make it worth the engineering effort.

Comment: Erm... I'm mostly doing it because of the challenge :) I'm still learning Android development (which your book has been a great help with).

Comment: @RobinJ: If you have my book, I have a chapter on plugins, starting on page 2287 of Version 6.2 of the book (released a few hours ago).

Comment: Awesome! I'll download the new version and have a look! :)

Comment: I've read the chapter in your book, and while I still think it'd be an interesting challenge, I don't think I'm prepared to deal with the security implications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An actual app that uses plugins might give you ideas. Here is the plugin developer page of an app that uses them:

http://www.twofortyfouram.com/developer